# improving cypher query performance and find bottleneck in cypher with jdbc to neo4j server connection

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j, cypher

I'm looking for methods to improve the answer time of my neo4j server, respectively the cypher querying. 
I've got a server with neo4j running. My neo4j graph is around 55GB. There are 4 different node types, where on each is an index.
From a client I'm running from java code with jdbc connector a lot(>1000) of queries, like the following:

```
    MATCH (p0:Page {title:'"+captionU+"'}), (p1:Page {title:'"+labelU+"'}), p = ((p0)-[r:To_Category*..4]-(p1)) RETURN p
```

According to the neo4j webconsole such a query takes around 4000ms. Using the server shell, shows a similar amount of time(~4000ms). 
Especially when running my java code some of the queries seem to require
much more time than 4000ms. setQueryTimeout does not have any effect.

1. So besides buying new hardware for the server, does anyone have an idea of tweaking the jdbc connector or the cypher querying?
2. Does anyone have an idea how to find this bottleneck? In the jdbc logs I do not find something that might give a hint to the problem.
3. On the server permission denied warning appears for $ echo 'deadline' > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an index on `:Page(title)`? Have you profiled the query in the browser? (i.e. if you have an index are you sure it is being used) Can you make your path match directed? How unique are page titles?

Comment: it would be interesting what the number of results actually is. Instead of `RETURN p` try `RETURN count(p)`. Do you really need all paths up level before between the two nodes or are you just interest in the shortest one? If so, use `shortestPath` in the the match.

Comment: Hi Dave, I've got an index on each Node type so in my case  'ON :Page(title) ONLINE, ON :Category(title) ONLINE, ON :CCat(title) ONLINE, ON :File(title) ONLINE'. Yes, profiled in Browser. Can you tell me, how to make sure/test that it is being used? I thought it is when using the 'p0:Page {title:' constraint. I  even don't understand the 'path match directed' question, can you give me an example? All page titles are unique. Thank you for your reply. @Stefan: I'm doing some analysis stuff on these result paths, so I'm interested in all the paths given for a query.Thank you for your comment

Comment: By directed i mean can you add a direction to the path match like this `(p0)-[r:To_Category*..4]->(p1)`.  If the index is being employed the plan should show that it is using **NodeIndexSeek** to find your starting points. Per Stefan's comment there could be many paths returned.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. Making the path match directed results in 0 rows. My graph do not have directions. According to the Profile Match-command NodeIndexSeek is used. Such a query retrieves ~250 nodes and ~3130 relationships.